# How do I loop a Django Queryset in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views

How can I loop a Django model queryset in javascript. I have a music player that uses javascript and the 'trackUrl' variable inside the javascript lists the track paths, I need to be able to loop through each users uploaded tracks and load them into the player for each user. I basically need to get the track out from the Music model, for each user.

Hopefully this makes sense , here's some of the code i have now.

models.py

```
class Music(models.Model):
    track = models.FileField(upload_to='path/to/audio')
    title = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    artwork = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', blank=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

music.js

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    var playerTrack = $("#player-track"), bgArtwork = $('#bg-artwork'), bgArtworkUrl,
     albumName = $('#album-name'), trackName = $('#track-name'), albumArt = $('#album-art'),
      sArea = $('#s-area'), seekBar = $('#seek-bar'), trackTime = $('#track-time'), insTime = $('#ins-time'),
       sHover = $('#s-hover'), playPauseButton = $("#play-pause-button"),  i = playPauseButton.find('i'), 
       tProgress = $('#current-time'), tTime = $('#track-length'), seekT, seekLoc, seekBarPos, cM, ctMinutes, 
       ctSeconds, curMinutes, curSeconds, durMinutes, durSeconds, playProgress, bTime, nTime = 0, buffInterval = null, 
       tFlag = false, albums = ['Dawn','Me & You','Electro Boy','Home','Proxy (Original Mix)'], 
       trackNames = ['Skylike - Dawn','Alex Skrindo - Me & You','Kaaze - Electro Boy','Jordan Schor - Home','Martin Garrix - Proxy'], 
       albumArtworks = ['_1','_2','_3','_4','_5'], trackUrl = 
      ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/music-player-1/master/music/2.mp3',
       'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/music-player-1/master/music/1.mp3',
       'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/music-player-1/master/music/3.mp3',
       'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/music-player-1/master/music/4.mp3',
       'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/music-player-1/master/music/5.mp3'], 
       playPreviousTrackButton = $('#play-previous'), playNextTrackButton = $('#play-next'), currIndex = -1;

    function playPause()
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

[Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) creates an api that allows the front-end to interact with your models. so after setting up django rest framework you can then use something like axios to make requests to the api and get your model data.

alternatively you can create a custom view function in your views.py that grabs the model data you need and then you customize it into a useable format for JavaScript (like json format for example) and then return that data. then on the client side you just make a request with axios to that view function you just created and it sends you that json data.